# Microsoft Graph API: Allow Move action outside me user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Currently all graph API access tokens have a scope within the me context. Is there any way to move a message to a folder outside the user scope. Eg: Move a message from user1's folder to user2's folder using graph access token.

We can do this using outlook ecp mailflow rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible with Microsoft Graph. Moves and copies can only happen within the same mailbox.